# Node.js: how to loop through handling incoming data?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have received this comment:

On the server side of Node.js when handling incoming data if you want to use a `for` loop you have to create `i` inside an anonymous function or you will pull your hair out wondering how the hell your variable `i` is greater than what you limit it to be inside your loop.

Here is the bugfix that was recommended:

```
var i = 0,
len = that.users.length;

(function(i) {
  while(i < len) {
    console.log(' - - - - - debug - - - - -');
    console.log('i = ' + i );
    i++;
  }
})(i);
```

Can someone explain to me why using an anonymous function is necessary?

Answer (score 1):

The problem only shows up when you have asynchronous code inside the loop.  For example (I changed to a for loop for simplicity):

```
var i = 0,
len = that.users.length;

for(i = 0;i < len;i++) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('i = ' + i );
  }, 500);
}
```

You will find that running this code causes the value of `len` to be printed `len` times, instead of a count up to `len`.  This is because the for loop finishes before any of the print statements run, so the loop has exited because `i == len`.

The fix for this is to lock `i` in to each value with an Immediately-Invoked Function Expression (IIFE):

```
var i = 0,
len = that.users.length;

for(i = 0;i < len;i++) {
  (function(i) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log('i = ' + i );
    }, 500);
  })(i);
}
```

This isn't exactly the bugfix you presented, but it is the closest I can think of that makes much sense.  Given more context, I could be more sure about what problem it is supposed to solve.